# Is there any way to replace attributes with item objects inside this display_table method?

Tags: ruby

Creating a program to get calculate sales tax as per provided details and some standard rates defined in this program. Now I want to simplify this format display class by replacing attributes inside "@max_length_fields[@data_array[0][i]]}s" and replace it with objects.

I have tried to push all fields directly inside this class but that further complicates the code. 
The Data array used within Format display class is pushed from another Invoice class containing method names as create_data_array :

```
  def create_data_array
    data_array = []
    data_array.push(["name", "imported", "exempted", "price", "price including tax"])
    @item_list.each do |item|
      data_array.push([item.name, item.imported, item.exempted, item.price, item.price_including_tax])
    end
    data_array
  end
```

Now I want to simplify the code by using item objects rather using attributes inside array, class below displays final output of this program and need to be rectified -

```
class FormatDisplay
  def initialize(data_array)
    @data_array = data_array
    @max_length_fields = {}
    @column_width = 0
    @data_array[0].each { |field| @max_length_fields[field] = field.length}
  end

  def display_table
    @data_array.each do |fieldset|
      row_string = ''
      fieldset.each_with_index do |field, i|
        row_string += '| ' + sprintf("%#{@max_length_fields[@data_array[0][i]]}s", field) + " "
      end
      puts row_string
    end
  end
end
```

Expected Result : Replacing attribute from "@max_length_fields[@data_array[0][i]]}s" with item object something like option.title

Comment: Are you getting the output you want? If not, can you show the desired output?

Comment: Yes I'm getting correct output. I just wanted to implement it in another way.

Comment: Name of the product: egg
Imported?: y
Exempted from sales tax? n
Price: 56
Do you want to add more items to your list(y/n): n
| name | imported | exempted | price | price including tax 
|  egg |        y |        n |  56.0 |                56.0

Comment: Above is the sequence of questions asked from user and then based on them final list get displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right this would work

```
def create_data_array
  item_list.map do |item|
    {
      name: item.name,
      imported: item.imported,
      exempted: item.exempted,
      price: item.price,
      price_including_tax: item.price_including_tax
    }
  end
end

class FormatDisplay
  def initialize(data_array)
    @data_array = data_array
    @column_width = 0
  end

  def display_table
    @data_array.each do |fieldset|
      row_string = ''

      fieldset.each_pair do |key, value|
        row_string += '| ' + sprintf("%#{ key.size }s", value) + ' '
      end

      puts row_string
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome.. thanks a lot, with few adjustments it worked.

Comment: One small request, Can you please also explain a bit how below code works ?            row_string += '| ' + sprintf("%#{ key.size }s", value) + ' '                           Specifically key.size

Comment: @Abhishek key.size is the same as key.length and returns length of string or symbol.